# DropdownFormField in flutter not loading intital values in release mode

Tags: flutter

I am using this below customFormField in my flutter web application, mostly everywhere, It works as expected in the debug mode, but running in release mode, the initial value provided to the formfield is not displayed

I have checked for some solutions, I have tried converting this statefulWidget and settting State after a 100 milliseconds in initState.
I have added key:ValueKey(value) , if there's any tree shaking.
That didn't work either. and there were several threads opened on same issue, but closed without solution,

//edit
I have tried running in Profile mode as well, It didn't work

Below is my env and code.

I'm using Flutter 3.7.12. Dart 2.19.6, Problem occurs in all browsers

```
class CustomDropdownFormField<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomDropdownFormField({super.key, this.items, this.onChanged, this.value, required this.title, this.validator});

  final List<DropdownMenuItem<T>>? items;
  final void Function(T?)? onChanged;
  final T? value;
  final String title;
  final String? Function(T?)? validator;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(title),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        DropdownButtonFormField<T>(
          value: value,
          items: items,
          onChanged: onChanged,
          validator: validator,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.indigo.shade50,
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```